# ¿cómo comparo los números de dos matrices en c#?

Tags: c#

Bien, me encuentro atascado en un ejercicio básico de matrices y no encuentro la solución. En este caso es el usuario quien tiene que decirme de que tamaño de dos matrices `A` y `B`, posteriormente tiene que introducir los datos en forma de número de cada matriz.

Después tengo que comparar el tamaño de ambas matrices que hasta este punto sin problema, ya que sin son de diferente tamaño se termina el programa pero si son de igual tamaño tengo que pasar a comparar cada número de cada matriz y si son iguales sacar un mensaje y si son diferente sacar otro.

```
{
        string linea;

        Console.WriteLine("Cuantas filas quieres que tenga la primera matriz:");
        linea = Console.ReadLine();
        int fila1 = int.Parse(linea);
        Console.WriteLine("Cuantas columanas quieres que tenga la primera matriz");
        linea = Console.ReadLine();
        int colu1 = int.Parse(linea);

        //array matriz1
        int[,] mat1 = new int[fila1, colu1];

        //leer datos y guardarlos en la matriz1
        for(int f = 0; f < mat1.GetLength(0); f++)
        {
            for(int c=0; c<mat1.GetLength(1); c++)
            {
                Console.Write("Introduce los valores de la primera matriz:");
                linea = Console.ReadLine();
                //leemos convertimos y asignamos
                mat1[f,c] = int.Parse(linea);
            }

        }

        //pedimos al usuario los datos de la segunda matriz
        Console.WriteLine("Cuantas filas quieres que tenga la segunda matriz:");
        linea = Console.ReadLine();
        int fila2 = int.Parse(linea);
        Console.WriteLine("Cuantas columanas quieres que tenga la segunda matriz");
        linea = Console.ReadLine();
        int colu2 = int.Parse(linea);

        //array matriz2
        int[,] mat2 = new int[fila2, colu2];

        //leer datos y guardarlos en la matriz2
        for (int f = 0; f < mat2.GetLength(0); f++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < mat2.GetLength(1); c++)
            {
                Console.Write("Introduce los valores de la segunda matriz:");
                linea = Console.ReadLine();
                //leemos convertimos y asignamos
                mat2[f, c] = int.Parse(linea);
            }

        }

        //imprimir en conosola la primera matriz
        Console.WriteLine("La Matriz1 tiene estos valores:");
        for (int f = 0; f < mat1.GetLength(0); f++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < mat1.GetLength(1); c++)
            {

                Console.Write(mat1[f, c]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        //imprimir en conosola la segunda matriz
        Console.WriteLine("La Matriz2 tiene estos valores:");
        for (int f = 0; f < mat2.GetLength(0); f++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < mat2.GetLength(1); c++)
            {
                Console.Write(mat2[f, c]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        // pasamos a comparar la matriz 1 y la matriz 2

        if (fila1 == fila2 && colu1 == colu2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Las matrices si pueden ser comparadas");
            Console.WriteLine();
            for (int f = 0; f < GetLength(0); f++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < GetLength(1); c++)
                {
                   if (mat1[f,c] == mat2[f,c])
                   {
                    Console.WriteLine("Las matrices son iguales");
                   }
                   else Console.WriteLine("Las matrices no son iguales");
                }
            }
        }
        else Console.WriteLine("Las matrices no pueden ser comparadas");
```

Encontré una solución para recorrer las matrices y ver su valores y saber si eran iguales o no:

```
// comparar tamaño de la matriz 1 y la matriz 2

        bool iguales = true;//Generar un booleano para posteriormente comparar los valores de las matrices que son de igual tamaño

        if (fila1 == fila2 && colu1 == colu2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Las matrices si pueden ser comparadas");
            //recorrer matrices y las comparar valores
            for (int j = 0; j < fila1; j++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < colu1; i++)
                {
                    if (mat1[j, i] != mat2[j, i])
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("La matriz 1 tiene en {0} {1}: {2} y en matriz 2 {0} {1}: {3}", j, i, mat1[j, i], mat2[j, i]);
                        iguales = false;
                        break;
                    }

                }

            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            if (iguales)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Las matrices son iguales");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Las matrices no son iguales");
            }

        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Las matrices no pueden ser comparadas");
        }
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que leas [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta. En el sitio no se resuelven ejercicios de clase, a no ser que se muestre qué se ha intentado y se explique claramente en que parte en concreto se están teniendo dificultades.

Comment: Solo necesitas dos bucles `for`. Lo que vas a comparar son los elementos que estan en la misma posicion `i,j`. Luego compara `mat1[i,j]` con `mat2[i,j]`.

Comment: y eso lo hago for(int f=0; f<GetLength (0);f++) perdona mi ignorancia pero estoy empezando con la programación y creo nos pusieron un ejercicio difícil nada mas iniciar el curso....

Comment: Dado que cuando llegas ahi ya has comprobado que las matrices son iguales de tamaño, simplemente usa un bucle `for (int i = 0; i < mat1.GetLength(0); i++)`y dentro uno `for (int j = 0; j < mat1.GetLength(1); j++)`.

Comment: y de esa manera me está comparado los datos de las dos matrices¿? pensaba que así solo recorrería una de las matrices.

Comment: esos dos bucles lo unico que hacen es que i y j tomen los valores desde 0 hasta el numero de filas y columnas que tienen las matrices. Donde realmente accedes a las matrices es en la comparacion, haciendo `mat1[i,j] == mat2[i,j]`.

Comment: if (fila1 == fila2 && colu1 == colu2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Las matrices si pueden ser comparadas");
                Console.WriteLine();

                if (mat1[fila1, colu1] == mat2[fila2, colu2])
                    for (int f = 0; f < mat1.GetLength(0); f++)
                    {
                        for (int c = 0; c < mat1.GetLength(1); c++)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Las matrices si son iguales");
                        }
                    }
De esta manera.....

Answer (score 2):

> ¿Cómo comparo los números de dos matrices en c#?

Índice a índice, si encuentras una coincidencia diferente: es que son diferentes.

```
bool compara(int[,] a, int[,] b)
{
    var la0 = a.GetLength(0);
    var la1 = a.GetLength(1);
    var lb0 = b.GetLength(0);
    var lb1 = b.GetLength(1);

    if ((la0 == lb0) && (la1 == lb1))
    {
        for (int f = 0; f != la0; ++f)
            for (int c = 0; c != la1; ++c)
                if (a[f,c] != b[f,c])
                    return false;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Las matrices no se pueden comparar");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Puedes mejorar tu código si la recopilación de datos se hace en una función, así evitas duplicidad de código:

```
static int[,] pide_matriz()
{
    string linea;

    Console.WriteLine("Cuantas filas quieres que tenga la matriz?");
    linea = Console.ReadLine();
    int fila = int.Parse(linea);

    Console.WriteLine("Cuantas columanas quieres que tenga la matriz?");
    linea = Console.ReadLine();
    int colu = int.Parse(linea);

    var result = new int[fila, colu];

    for (int c = 0; c != colu; ++c)
    {
        for (int f = 0; f != fila; ++f)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Valor para la fila {f} columna {c}:");
            linea = Console.ReadLine();
            result[f, c] = int.Parse(linea);
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("La Matriz tiene estos valores:");
    for (int c = 0; c != colu; ++c)
    {
        for (int f = 0; f != fila; ++f)
        {
            Console.Write($"{result[f,c]} ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Por lo que tu `Main` podría quedar así:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (compara(pide_matriz(), pide_matriz()))
        Console.WriteLine("Las matrices son iguales");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Las matrices son diferentes");
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVTfjxIxEH7e/hUjMZclhwS88/xBiA/34AsmF030gRBTlllssrTYdjFK9m/nptNyG3Q9fNAHoMx88/Wbb9oW7llhLB4OtVN6DR9/OI@biRBFJZ2DO2vWVm7EXmTOS68KUNrPBwvYqhV@2Uhv1c@8LzLKE8AGhkpplESQZbdGO1Ph8LNVHmcUznu3tdReOigV0cO3WqHF8IvgUa8lVBIi6dtef0IUTAZTOFJ9QLliJs6SFmYiAC2Hd9I6zLmkf05AYap6I/U/EhHY/iRiJy0Qf115Qmj8zg4G1QMuWzCoNBZyZiLQaEI/T6acnsDlZUEGs8MtrIywMsACV4CVARZxHZ0/7X2SFZVvpeUO2bd92UQnNK2L5k3s91zHWRb7mZfUwqKzb8I0Iny6pzCT8J4dBq9QI6DzxsEuCESXVPxXS8iO/UMTxaKBXiu6QzAnuRmLvrY6DZSiIZhuxtKYigRugsN5uiY05LRaplsSjkMlRyRWDt@hn9GJ81/zEe8Qc@NfcuM2t3ykbtlVF85nCXnOO04DQR8uLiDnXcL/cf9xJ6mwNbJ7JsT1MJIs7ifZ1ZBc8iqlju6VsnIYLc0ypPVRQudRcfE2FnRHtQGHsK1xhfpotU2j@527HZe3NZ4Oa2fUis6g0nl8tuY0K7t2aUihh@MkT166wenDx@adVe2MBrWuZYUuak0t/1XhSpX0PGmfahvRHA5X4kqMxXP6vhYvxI14KV6J16KN3lD0OkXvAQ)</kbd>.

Comment: En el método `compara`, `lb0` y `lb1` deben obtenerse del array `b` y no del `a`. Por otro lado, por convención, los métodos en C# empiezan con mayuscula ;)

Comment: @Pikoh "*Un copypaste, se balanceaba sobre la tela de una araña, como veía que generaba errores, fue a hacer otro copypaste. Dos copypaste, se balanceaban sobre la tela de una araña, como veían que generaban errores, fueron a hacer otro copypaste. Tres copypaste, se balanceaban sobre la tela de una araña, como veían que generaban errores, fueron a hacer otro copypaste. Cuatro copypaste, se balanceaban sobre la tela de una araña, como veían que generaban errores, fueron a hacer otro copypaste. Cinco copypaste, se balanceaban sobre la tela de una araña, como veían que generaban errores…*"

Comment: Espero que para hacer ese comentario hicieras copypaste

Comment: La duda ofende.

Comment: Gracias por el aporte, pero esa manera es una manera muy limpia de escribir código, tengo que aprender a razonar y muchos de los conceptos que has escrito en el código todavía no se han visto por lo que no puedo usarlos. Seguiré investigando y buscando una solución que me ayude a razonar lo que estoy haciendo.

Comment: @DavidDiaz Es imposible que estés en un curso de programación y no te hayan explicado conceptos como funciones y bucles.

Comment: solo bucles y condicionales y solo podemos trabajar en el main.

Comment: @DavidDiaz estoy horrorizado con lo mal que se enseña a programar hoy en día.

Comment: pues si encima privado. además los que partimos de 0 estamos super perdidos respecto a los que tienen algún conocimiento.
mira he pensando si:
En mi primer if (fila1 == fila2 && colu1 == colu2) aquí son iguales en tamaño debe entrar a recorrer las matrices. sino pongo else y directamente termina con no son iguales.

Comment: Bien si dentro del primer if se cumple la condición.
Recorro las filas de las dos matrices para saber si son iguales los datos del usuario. Hasta este punto bien¿?

Comment: Lo que estás describiendo es lo que hace la función `compara`